# Reset File Permissions for Jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-permissions, jekyll, chmod

I accidentally ran the command `sudo chmod 600 -R /` when I meant to do it to `sudo chmod 600 -R Documents/some_directory` and my macbook pro's file permissions got messed up. I ran `sudo chmod 755 -R /directories_that_don't_need_to_be_secure` and tried to fix all the permissions. But when I start my Jekyll server `jekyll --server --auto` everything is forbidden. I made my whole directory readable, writable, and executable. But the error keeps popping up. This is what I get when the jekyll server generates

```
    Shalin-Shah-Me:shalin shalinvs$ jekyll --server --auto
Configuration from /Users/shalinvs/Documents/Developer/Websites/shalin/_config.yml
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sass (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/shalinvs/Documents/Developer/Websites/shalin/_plugins/sass_converter.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:78:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:77:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:77:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:31:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/jekyll:238:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/jekyll:238
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23
```

I have also tried using Disk Utility to repair my permissions but still no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jekyll command operates on the directory you are currently in. The output in your question shows that you're running it in your home directory. It seems unlikely that that's really where you have your jekyll site stored (especially since it means that jekyll would have to process everything in your home directory each time it runs).

Assuming that you have your jekyll files somewhere else, change to that directory (where you should see the _config.yml and other jekyll files/dirs) and try running the command there.

Comment: Good to make at least a little progress. Since you are getting that new error, I'd suggest opening a new question that focuses on it directly. Before that, try googling for 'gem_original_require' and see what you can dig up. I'd also suggest removing everything and then adding things back in one piece at a time so you can figure out exactly which part isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Disk Utility.app has a Fix Permissions module. Perhaps that would solve it?

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it was unsuccessful. I will add that in my question. Thanks for reminding me!